# Uploading files in php (doing nothing)

Tags: php, file, upload

```
<?php
$pagetitle='Userfiles';
include 'includes/header.php';
if($_POST)
{
    if(count($_FILES)>=0)
        {
        if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], 
                'Files'.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.$_FILES['file']['name']))
            {
                echo 'You uploaded your file successfully!';
            }
            else {
                echo 'Error';
            }
        }
}
?> 
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div><input type="file" name="file"></div>
    <div><input type="submit" value="Upload"></div>
</form>
<?php
include 'includes/footer.php';
?>
```

I want to upload some files. Probably the simplest idea but it doesn't work and I don't know why. Any suggestions why when I press Upload the file just disappears?

Comment: Define "it doesn't work". You might want to read [How do I ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), which enhances the probability for getting a useful answer _drastically_. You might find [ESR](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eric_S._Raymond)'s excellent essay [How To Ask Questions The Smart Way](http://catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html) helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You problem is that you're checking the `$_POST` superglobal when you should in fact check only `$_FILES` superglobal:

```
<?php
$pagetitle='Userfiles';
include 'includes/header.php';
if($_FILES)
{
    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'],
            'Files'.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.$_FILES['file']['name']))
        {
            echo 'You uploaded your file successfully!';
        }
        else {
            echo 'Error';
        }
}
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div><input type="file" name="file"></div>
    <div><input type="submit" value="Upload"></div>
</form>
<?php
include 'includes/footer.php';
?>
```